# I cannot use all the Microsoft SQL Server sequences because of the error "Invalid object name <sequence>."

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I cannot use all the Microsoft SQL Server sequences because of the error `Invalid object name <sequence>.`

The problem affects Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (but also Microsoft SQL Server 2018).
I have created a user named `WebClient1` in SQL Server Management Studio (Microsoft SQL Server 2012).
I cannot use all the Microsoft SQL Server sequences because of the error `Invalid object name <sequence>.`

I have created the following sequence:

```
USE [AlphaShop]
GO

USE [AlphaShop]
GO

/****** Object:  Sequence [dbo].[Test_Seq]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 10:56:28 ******/
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[Test_Seq] 
 AS [bigint]
 START WITH 500
 INCREMENT BY 50
 MINVALUE 500
 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
 CACHE 
GO
```

The SQL query is the following:

```
select
    next_val as id_val 
from
    Test_Seq with (updlock,
    rowlock)
```

The error is:

```
Messaggio 208, livello 16, stato 3, riga 1
Il nome di oggetto 'Test_Seq' non è valido.
```

The translation might be the following:

```
Message 208, level 16, state 3, row 1
Invalid object name 'Test_Seq'.
```

In the object explorer, I can see the sequence "dbo.Test_Seq".
The name of the database is AlphaShop.
In the available databases listbox, I have selected the correct database, AlphaShop.

The authentication type of the user is "Authentication of SQL Server".
The user has the role "public".
Please help.
Many thanks in advance.

I tried to execute the following SQL command, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
ALTER LOGIN WebClient1 WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [AlphaShop];
```

```
select
    next_val as id_val 
from
    Test_Seq with (updlock,
    rowlock)
```

The expected results consist of the next value of the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `FROM` it's `FOR`. `NEXT VALUE` doesn't return a dataset (it's not a table-value function) it returns a scalar value, so you reference in it the `SELECT`, not the `FROM`:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Test_Seq AS id_val;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cd58089663760a2a46184485c2ccc0a)

Comment: If in doubt, the documentation on SQL Server is incredibly complete, @dbedit . The documentation gives an example in the Example section: [CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL) - Examples: Creating a sequence using all arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#g-creating-a-sequence-using-all-arguments)